# AWS Lambda, no longer provides default access to aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

Havent used aws in a while and it seems some changes have been made. I tried making a lambda function that connects to cognito today, but when I test it i get an error:

the first line in the function is :

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
```

the error in cloudwatch:

> "Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs"

I read some stuff suggesting a work around creating a layer and uploading a zip file with some shareable code that includes the sdk, but I dont want to do that. Is aws-sdk really no longer accessible by default in a lambda function?

Comment: What version of the AWS SDK libraries are you dependent on?  Which version of the Node runtime are you using?  The Node 18 runtime uses version 3 of the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: According to this it is still included. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Comment: for the sdk ill use whatever works, it doesnt matter for this project. the node version is the default (i think 18).

Comment: One thing i am using differently is the arm architecture. Not sure if that makes a difference here.

Comment: The `aws-sdk` package is AWS SDK v2 which is available in nodejs16.x and lower runtime environments. For nodejs18.x you can use the v3 SDK which is modular and imported by module, for example via `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`.

Comment: Yup, thats what is up. thanks!